# Is there a memory leak?

Tags: c++, string, class, memory, memory-leaks

I have tried to write my own String class in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I wrote the class like this;

```
#include<string.h>
class myString {
    private:
        char* content;
    public:
        int size;
        myString();
        myString(char*);
        ~myString();
        bool operator==     (const myString &) const;
        bool operator!=     (const myString &) const;
        myString operator=  (const myString &);
        myString operator+  (const myString &) const;
        myString operator+= (const myString &);
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const myString &);
        char operator[] (int &) const;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const myString &string) {
    os << string.content;
    return os;
}

myString::myString() {
    size = 0;
    content = "\0";
}

myString::myString(char* newContent) {
    size = strlen(newContent);
    content = new char[size+1];
    strcpy(content, newContent);
}

myString::~myString() {
    delete[] content;
}

myString myString::operator= (const myString &string) {
    if (size != string.size) {
        delete[] content;
        size = string.size;
        content = new char[size+1];
    }
    strcpy(content, string.content);
    return *this;
}

bool myString::operator== (const myString &string) const {
    if (size != string.size)
        return false;
    if (strcmp(content, string.content))
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool myString::operator!= (const myString &string) const {
    if (*this == string)
        return false;
    return true;
}

myString myString::operator+ (const myString &string) const {
    int newSize = size + string.size;
    char* newContent = new char[newSize];
    strcpy(newContent, content);
    strcat(newContent, string.content);
    return myString(newContent);
}

myString myString::operator+= (const myString &string) {
    *this = *this + string;
    return *this;
}

char myString::operator[] (int &index) const {
    return content[index];
}
```

It works fine when I tried to do this;

```
#include<iostream>
#include "MyString.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    myString s("my new");
    cout << s+" string" << endl;    
}
```

But I am not sure if there is any memory leak in `operator+` function in the line `char* newContent = new char[newSize];` I am allocating new space from the memory and I need it in the return statement `return myString(newContent);`.

So I can not deallocate it before this line and I can not deallocate it after the return statement. Am I correct, is there a memory leak? If so, how can I fix this?

**EDIT 1 :**
I've changed the `operator+` function as follows with the help of Prince Dhaliwal;

```
myString myString::operator+ (const myString &string) const {
    myString temp;
    int newSize = size + string.size;
    char* newContent = new char[newSize + 1];
    temp.size = newSize;
    strcpy(newContent, content);
    strcat(newContent, string.content);
    temp.content = newContent;
    return temp;
}
```

But since I created the `temp` locally it calls its destructor before returning it and gives error. I supposed I should allocate memory for temp too. And I changed the function as follows;

```
myString myString::operator+ (const myString &string) const {
    myString* temp= new myString;
    int newSize = size + string.size;
    char* newContent = new char[newSize+1];
    temp->size = newSize;
    strcpy(newContent, content);
    strcat(newContent, string.content);
    temp->content = newContent;
    return *temp;
}
```

It works fine now, but I believe there is still memory leak because of the `temp` variable. If there is a memory leak, how to fix this?

**EDIT 2 :**
I've fixed it simply by creating a Copy Constructor

Comment: Profile your code, then you know if there's a memory leak. If so, you can try to find where.

Comment: Why would you do this when STL has a string class?

Comment: Actually this is from my homework and they forbade us to use them. I guess for the learning purposes.

Comment: Yes, there is a memory leak as you describe.

Comment: Oh I see, you haven't created the copy constructor `myString(const myString&)`. What actually is happening that the default copy constructor will do memberwise copying which means that both the copy and the original pointers `content` were pointing to the same memory. That memory got deleted when the `temp`'s destructor was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a memory leak in your code. When you are using the `+` operator in `s + " string"`. In your `operator+()` definition i.e.

```
myString myString::operator+ (const myString &string) const {
    int newSize = size + string.size;
    char* newContent = new char[newSize];
    strcpy(newContent, content);
    strcat(newContent, string.content);
    return myString(newContent);
}
```

You are allocating the new string here `char* newContent = new char[newSize];`, copying the older and new part to the new string. And again you are allocating the new string in the constructor `return myString(newContent);`. But where are you deleting your old string? Its nowhere in your code. So you have to delete the string `newContent`.
You can do this

```
myString myString::operator+ (const myString &string) const {
    myString temp;
    int newSize = size + string.size;
    char* newContent = new char[newSize + 1];
    temp.size = newSize;
    strcpy(newContent, content);
    strcat(newContent, string.content);
    temp.content = newContent;
    return temp;
}
```

UPDATE
You have to create a copy constructor.

```
myString(const myString &rhs) :
size(rhs.size) {
    content = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(content, rhs.content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way shouldn't we write newSize+1 when we allocate the memory for newContent, because of the '\0' character?

Comment: Besides, we created the temp string locally. So when this operator+ function finishes, it calls temp's destructor. How should I handle this?

Comment: Before `temp`'s destructor will be called, it will be copied as you are returning the copy of the local variable which is fine.

Comment: I used the debugger of Visual Studio. In the return line, before it returns temp it goes the dectructor of temp, clears the content and returns a string with no content and it gives error when I tried to print its content.

Comment: We should use the newSize + 1 for `\0`. I made the changes in code.

Comment: Yes, it was giving errors, now they are fixed. But other error still occurs. I tried something and edited my question. Is there a memory leak now?

Comment: Yes, there is still memory leak. You are now creating the temp dynamically and returning the copy of the memory pointed by temp which is not deleted.

Comment: How can I delete that memory? I couldn't find anywhere to delete it.

Comment: Create a copy constructor. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, it works perfectly now!